# Access Site Collection in Powershell with Client Id and Client Secret?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is there a way to Create a context in powershell using Client Id and Client Secret ?

Currently I am using `$context.Credentials` in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PnP PowerShell to connect to SharePoint using client id as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <url> -AppId <clientid> -AppSecret <clientsecret>
$context = Get-PnPContext
```

Reference - [Connect-PnPOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps)

Download - [PnP PowerShell releases](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

If you have PowerShellGet installed, you can directly install it using `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`